# Retreiving TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have sample code I have applied window size of three, now I need the first value of the windows provided by the GetShiftingWindows based on a condition if its equal to one and store that one in the second column of the data frame.

for instance, the output I am retrieving is below, I need the first value of the list if its equal to one but in the below output it's not working as expected and its providing error

```
[0, 0, 1]
1
[0, 1, 0]
1
[1, 0, 0]
1
[0, 0, 1]
1
```

Code
the desired output expected

```
[0, 0, 1]
0
[0, 1, 0]
0
[1, 0, 0]
1
[0, 0, 1]
0

def GetShiftingWindows(data, size):
    return [ data[x:x+size] for x in range( len(data) - size + 1 ) ]

df = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,1,1]

df1=pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Labels'])
df1['Improved']=np.NaN

list=GetShiftingWindows(df1['Labels'], 3)


for i in list:
  for index, j in enumerate(i,start=1):
    if j==1:
       df1['Improved'][j]=j[0]
```

Retrieving below error:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-bb0991d40acd> in <module>()
      3       for index, j in enumerate(i,start=1):
      4         if j==1:
----> 5            df1['Improved'][j]=j[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: j is 1 so what should `j[0]` mean?

Comment: if `j` is an int then `j[0]` is invalid.

Comment: @doublesharp  thanks, Yes j[0] is an int value which is the first item in the list

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you for your response,  Yes j[0] is an int value which is the first item in the list

Comment: @abaairdavis `j` cannot be both an int value  `if j==1` and at the same time a list `j[0]`

Comment: @abaairdavis you are incorrect, you are treating an `int` as if it is an `array`. maybe you mean to use `list`?

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over an array and you said you wanted the first item of the list if any of the element is 1.

```
for i in list:
  for index, j in enumerate(i,start=1):
    if j==1:
       # Change here, i[0] is the first element 
       df1['Improved'][j]=i[0]
```

Comment: Did you even test this?

Comment: @Kinshukdua, its giving error, ValueError: 0 is not in range